# Push Sonarqube coverage results of a single test

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a typescript project with coverage being run by instanbul and mocha. I currently only have one test file, however when I try to push the coverage results to Sonarqube by using the setting

```
sonar.tests=directory/test.js
```

I get an error that results in

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The folder 'directory/test.js' does not exist

Does anyone know how I can get the coverage of a single test rather than sonarqube treating it as a folder?

Comment: Which plugin do you use to analyse TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters "sonar.tests" should be a directory. So to not get error just do

```
sonar.tests=directory
```

Comment: I have another project that lists individual tests and that works fine though. I don't want it to look at everything in this particular folder.

Comment: @annedroiid Are you using [sonar.test.inclusions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)?